# calculating gradient vector on rotated unit square

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What is the grad vector on the center(0.5,0.5,0) of the unit square [0,1] x [0,1] rotated by 45 deg around x axis?

The four coordinates and their function value after rotation are:

first point  f(0, 0.14) =  -0.35

second point f(1, 0.14) = -0.35

third point  f(1, 0.85) = 0.35

fourth point f(0, 0.85) = 0.35

And the center remains as f(0.5, 0.5) =0

I assume gradient vector is always perpendicular to the surface but they way I calculated(below), is coming tangent to the surface. Could anyone explain what I have done wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Gradient of which function?

Comment: a function that defines the surface of this unit square rotated 45 deg around x axis & about its centre

Comment: Which unit square? $[0,1] \times [0,1]$? Or is it centered at the origin? At what point are you evaluating the gradient?

Comment: Yes [0,1]x[0,1] where the center is (0.5,0.5). I have updated the question.

Comment: And when you rotate, what is the axis? The origin? Or the center?

Comment: It is explained in the question. About its center and around X axis

Comment: Sorry about the the question not being clear enough. The third coordinate z was the function value. I have updated the question. Hope its more clear now.